# Django: Is there a way to have the "through" model in a ManyToManyField in a different app to the model containing the ManyToManyField?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-apps, manytomanyfield

Lets say I have two django apps:

- **competitions** - which will handle competition data
- **entries** - which will handle functionality relating to entering competitors into competitions

In the competitions app I have a model which represents a section of a competition:

```
class Division(models.Model):
    competition = models.ForeignKey(Competition)
    discipline = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=DISCIPLINE_CHOICES)
    age_group = models.ForeignKey(AgeGroup)
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(Competitor, through='Entry')
```

I want to put the Entry model in the entries app:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    division = models.ForeignKey('Division')
    competitor = models.ForeignKey(Competitor)
    withdrawn = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How do I solve the from ... import ... statements, so that they work? When I put in import statements such as `from entries.models import Entry` I get the models from these apps ignored by syncdb (because the imports are circular) or when I remove one or both of them I get validation errors:

> Error: One or more models did not
>   validate: entries.entry: 'division'
>   has a relation with model Division,
>   which has either not been installed or
>   is abstract. competitions.division:
>   'participants' specifies an m2m
>   relation through model Entry, which
>   has not been installed

I understand why this happens, but I have no idea how to change this, so that it works (without resorting to moving the Entry model into the competitions app, which I really don't want to do).

Comment: can you post the `Competitor` class?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It seems like I've found an answer, which works more consistently :)

The [Django documentation on the ForeignKey class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) says:

> To refer to models defined in another
>   application, you can explicitly
>   specify a model with the full
>   application label. For example, if the
>   Manufacturer model above is defined in
>   another application called production,
>   you'd need to use:

```
class Car(models.Model):
    manufacturer = models.ForeignKey('production.Manufacturer')
```

> This sort of reference can be useful
>   when resolving circular import
>   dependencies between two applications.

Answer (score 5):

sometimes, `django.db.models.get_model` helps to work around circular imports. In your example, try to import `Entry` normally and chage the `division` FK definition in `Entry` to this:

```
from django.db.models import get_model

class Entry(models.Model):
    division = models.ForeignKey(get_model('competitions', 'Division'))
```

Comment: From what I can see this doesn't always work... I guess it depends on the order in which django loads the apps or something like that.
Still - very useful tip, thanks :)

Comment: ``get_model()`` might return ``None``.